# Laravel - Creating tables dynamically (without migration)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-schema

I'm trying to create a table dynamically upon an admin request, and while it seems it should be straightforward like most of Laravel's documentation, I can't seem to **create** a table. Though I can drop tables, and add or drop columns as I wish.

This is my basic code model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public static function createTable()
{
    Schema::create('randomName', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
    });
}
```

What could possibly be the problem here? Unfortunately I don't receive any errors so not sure how to debug it.

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Ugh, never mind... I worked on it for long enough, and the solution as always was... Very simple.

I just had to figure a connection for the database first, so instead of

```
Schema::create('tableName', function($table)
{           
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

It is

```
Schema::connection('mysql')->create('tableName', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

Hope this helps someone someday in the future!

Comment: Yes! Two months later it helped someone. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Shay! Still helpful in 2017!

Comment: Thanks a lot Shy! it's helping me in 2019, thanks for sharing your solution to us!

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks for informing back to us 

Answer (score 12):

This one is even better.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

Schema::create('tableName', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: It is exactly the same as Shay's answer.