# How to have Laravel Eloquents ORM autocreate a table in database?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

There [is a way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30560485/1711186) (also presented [here](https://medium.com/@CristianLLanos/eloquent-models-from-my-database-5d74c632e03c#.qg7cd4vri)) to have create Eloquent ORM Models (as a part of a Laravel app) based on a database.

I am looking for the inverse action. I would like to write some Eloquent Model classes
and have them being craeted as tables in the database.

How can this be done?

This [Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#introduction) does not feature any information. Can it be that while there is a often the case 1-to-1-mapping between the database and the eleoquent models a table canno tbe created automatically given a Eloquent Model was provided?

Comment: Use already answered questions [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560485/create-models-from-database-in-laravel-5) Hope it helps

Comment: @salmanfaris not really. I attempt to do the reverse, I have models and want to create the database content (i.e. have tables created to fit the models coded). The link you included in the comment has been already mentioned in my question, as an example to which I seek the **inverse** action to. thanks !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096105/laravel-creating-tables-dynamically-without-migration